# filter content type using taxonomy drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig

I display the articles content type in page--front.html.twig using 
`{{page.Articles}}` and it works. 
The articles content type includes “field_tags” (Taxonomy) and I want to show the articles based on the specific tag which is “food”.

How I can accomplish that without create a block. Thanks